# Create JQuery Terminal where prompt is always at the bottom

Tags: jquery, jquery-terminal

I've been using JQuery terminal for a project I'm working on. What I'd like is to have the terminal prompt always at the bottom of the terminal, rather than scrolling with whatever output there has been so far. Is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post effort and CODE

Comment: Why not ask the maker? http://terminal.jcubic.pl/

Comment: @mplungjan I've created jquery-terminal tag for that, also Q&A link on the website point to SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this css:

```
    .cmd {
        position: absolute !important;
        bottom: 10px;
        right: 10px;
        left: 10px;
        width: auto !important;
    }
    .terminal {
        overflow-y: hidden;
    }
    .terminal .terminal-output {
        max-height: calc(100% - 15px);
        overflow-y: auto;
    }
```

but note that you will not have scroll to bottom when you type something. And it will only look good if you enter only one line of text into command line, for it to work you will need to add some javascript.

I can try to create a demo that will work when you type more lines of text.

Comment: No worries, this is totally workable and helps me out greatly, thanks for the timely answer!